# In my Online multiplayer quiz game how can i make players to join and compete at a time?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-room

I am creating a multiplayer Online quiz game in Android Studio using Java. I am having players registered using Firebase in my app. Ok so the main thing is , I'm having different set of quiz tournaments like 10 players tournament, 20 player tournament ,30,40 etc., All tournaments are running one at a time.... For example Consider a 20 players tournament is about to begin, So 20 different players compete all together at a time and then rank is generated of those 20 players to calculate winning of those players (Rank is generated on the fact who clicked the answer button fastest).

I just want to know synopsis of how can I implement multiplayer in my app. **Most importantly i want to know how can i make the 20 players to play at a time and in a particular tournament**.

Comment: Use sockets to accomplish it

Comment: @Giancarlo Ventura  Friend Can you please show me , or share a link where its done. I am trying since last 2 days but failing everytime.  Also i want to ask can i do this without using sockets..i mean just by firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the first things you need to consider is how do you manage state for each game instance. What is a tournament? Do players play singleplayer, record their results, and whoever has the highest score wins the "tournament"? Do 20 players all compete at the same time in the same game?

The most common approach to synchronize game state in a particular instance is through a socket connection. What you would need to do is have a "match-making" server and a "game server".

The game server hosts a game and allows users to connect to it to be able to participate in the game. The match making server is what players connect to first. It is responsible for pooling players together in a "lobby" to start a new game (e.g. a player connects to the match-making server, the match-making server looks at the list of game servers that have not started yet and is not full and directs the player to that game server).

If you're gonna take this approach you would have to learn how to work with sockets.

Another option you can do is utilize Firebase realtime database. You would essentially store the same information. You query the database for available rooms, then set the player's database info to reflect the room that they were placed in.

Comment: Yes..20 players compete at the same time in  same game.  Also I am new to sockets , but used to Firebase Realtime database, Can you tell me if i use Firebase Realtime database , do i still need to use Sockets?  Or You are telling to chose one between Firebase or Socket?

Comment: With Firebase Realtime database, under the hood it works the same way, but you don't need to really learn about it. You just need to understand how to use the platform. Model your data to have "games", "players", "leaderboard", etc.. Then make queries. This approach is honestly the future. Horizontal scale via cloud computing.

Comment: Friend can you show me how to setup the "match-making" server and a "game server". I am trying since last 2 days but failing all the time.

Comment: https://www.twitch.tv/codecustard

Comment: The video uses Javascript, but it is essentially the same.... it goes over step by step as a beginner that has never used Firebase would go over it, using documentation and google. Take a look at the update/write/read methods for Java. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Friend , My bad that i dont know java script (so i didnt understood the video much).... Your video is totally in javascript. Also i want to know were you successful in implementing multiplayer ?

Comment: The main takeaway is understanding state. Instead of reading and writing state directly in your application, you read and write state from/to the cloud. Watch the video by thinking more abstractly and at a higher level. Remove all lower level concepts such as syntax and focus on the higher level concepts, and translate it to Java. Doing this, you can find resources written for Python, C++, etc... and use it for your usecase.

Comment: @codecustard I have been talking also with KumarHarsh and his tournament does not really happen in real time, since players just start ansering a given quiz (in paralel) the results of each question are stored and at the end of the tournament they get stored. so as long as the the answer to each question is stored linked to player and tournament, those are just INSERTS into the database, many can happen at the same time

Comment: All KumarHarsh needs is methods for : createTournament, listAllTournaments, answerQuestion, and similar, but there is no realtime interaction like a FPS shooter